# Is it possible to use more than one changeable divName in getelementbyid?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

In this sort of function

```
function someFunction(divName) 
{
    document.getElementById(divName).style.someproperty = 'something'
    document.getElementById(divName).style.someotherproperty = 'somethingelse'
}
```

called like this

```
onClick = "someFunction('someid')
```

Is there any way to have more than one divName that can be specified in the html?

e.g.

```
onClick = "someFunction('someid','someotherid')
```

The first getelementbyid being performed on 'someid' and the second on 'someotherid'

Preferably without jQuery

Edit:

I don't want to do the same thing to each of the two elements, I want to do something different to each individual element, but I want to be able to specify each element in the onClick ="..." instead of in the actual function, so that I don't have to write multiple functions for each combination of two target elements.

Sorry if that was unclear

**The Answer** (as it turns out, is really simple):

```
function someFunction(divName,divName2) 
{
    document.getElementById(divName).style.someproperty = 'something'
    document.getElementById(divName2).style.someotherproperty = 'somethingelse'
}
```

html

```
 onClick = "someFunction('someid','someotherid')"
```

When I tried it the first time, I wrote "someFunction('someid,someotherid')"
 and when it didn't work I assumed that the solution wasn't as easy as divname1,divname2

Sorry, for making all of you run around writing fancy codes.

Comment: Is this not the reason why we have classes?

Comment: I haven't been able to get classes to work, but that wouldn't be able to apply the same function to two specific id's in one instance and two different specific id's in another instance anyway.

Comment: Why don't you post some HTML and what you would like each element to do specifically and someone might be able to provide more specific help. But using classes is the way to go.

Comment: *You* created `someFunction`. Of course you can make the function accept two arguments, e.g. `divName` and `divName2` and use those parameters in the function. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I tried that and the divname2 one didn't work

Comment: You're right Felix King. Turns out it was a simple formatting problem when I tried that before. Now I feel really stupid.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get an arbitrary number of arguments for a function. You can use the special `arguments` variable that comes in every called function. It's an array-like object that contains each argument passed into the function, in the order you placed them in the call.

[You can do it like this](http://jsfiddle.net/3X9HF/):

```
function someFunction() {
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
    document.getElementById(arguments[i]).style.someproperty = 'something'
  }
}
```

However, classes might be better for this case, assuming you don't mind attaching classes to the target elements.

Comment: How do I specify which element it should apply a given property to?

Answer (score 0):

Give every your div a class name, for example "yourClass". Now you will have a function like this:

```
function someFunction(divClass) {
    var eles = document.getElementsByClassName(divClass); 
    eles.style.someproperty = 'something';
    eles.style.someproperty = 'something';
    for(var i = 0; i< eles.length; i++){
       // do some thing with each element
        eles[i].style.someproperty = 'something';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the parameter an array and loop through it.

```
function someFunction(divIDs)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById(divIDs[i]).style.someProperty = 'something';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is give all the elements you want to do something with a class which is the same for all of them, and an ID which is unique to all of them.

```
function someFunction(e) {
  var action = false;
  switch(e.target.id) {
  case 'someid': 
    action = 'something';
    break;
  case 'someotherid': 
    action = 'somethingelse';
    break;
  case default:
    break;
  }
  if(!action) return;
  document.getElementById(e.target.id).style.someProperty = action;
}
```

You would then assign the onclick handler to the class:

```
onClick = "someFunction('theClassName')
```

---

If you have more than one element which you want to do the same thing to, instead of using an id, you would add a second class to those elements and just change the function to look for that class.